# Why do I get "base table or view not found" when trying to use sprintf?

Tags: php

```
$sql = sprintf(
    'insert into $s ($s) values ($s)',
    $table,
    implode(', ', array_keys($parameters)),
    ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters))
);
try {
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute($parameters);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

OTHER FILE:

```
$query->test('todos', [
    'description' => $_POST['name'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastName'],
    'completed' => isset($_POST['finished'])
]);
```

It's weird cause if I do it manually instead it works perfectly

```
 $sql = "insert into $table (description, completed) values (:description, :completed)";
```

But when I use sprintf and implode it gives me an error saying "base table or view not found" Any ideas why?

Comment: Its ALWAYS a good idea to [Read the relevant manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) carefully before asking a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using `$`. [PHP Documentation For `sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$sql = sprintf(
    'insert into %s (%s) values (%s)',
    $table,
    implode(', ', array_keys($parameters)),
    ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters))
);
```

https://3v4l.org/2oEsT

Comment: Thansk! Can't believe I missed that